# Android emulator throw process system isn't responding error Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I add two platforms ios and android based on cordova documentation. The app can be easily deployed to ios emulator and run by issuing `cordova emulate ios`. However, I got a strange error says `process system isn't responding` in android emulator which is `Nexus S by Google` when issuing `cordova emulate android`. 
What I have done?

1. I installed jdk, and android 6.0 api 23 to work with my cordova 6.0.
2. I include the platforms-tools and tools in my .bash_profile

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools

The following screenshots are my android sdk manager, my avd configuration and the emulator error. I wonder what I missed????

[image: android sdk manager]

[image: android sdk manager]

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, you've got "CPU/ABI" set to "ARM". Is there an "x86" option available?